# remove() is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
function del(){
var i;
for(i = 2; i < 999; i++){
    var checkboxId = document.getElementById('checkbox' + i);
    if (checkboxId.checked == true){
        var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox' + i);
        checkbox.remove();
        var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text' + i);
        text.remove();
        var number = document.getElementsByClassName('number' + i);
        number.remove();
    }
}
```

}

Добрый день, выше код в котором я хочу чтоб елементы формы удалялись если чекбокс активирован, но ничего не выходит пишет ошибку: .remove() is not a function. В чем проблема?

Comment: getElementsByClassName возвращает массив элементов. В массива нет remove. Вам надо в цикле каждый элемент массива удалить.

Comment: @UserTest013 А судя по нумерации, там наверняка один элемент. `checkbox[0].remove();`, `text[0].remove();`. Автору: Больно же вручную прописывать числа для 999 элементов. Если getElementsByClassName возвращает список элементов, к которым можно обращатья через индекс, можно всем элементам выдать один класс, а нужный элемент брать через `[i]`